# ggvis: draw x-axis at y=0 with y-axis range e.g -100 to 100

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggvis

my dataset has negative and positive x and y values (e.g. range from -100 to 100). If I plot the data using the ggvis package in R, the axis-origins are drawn
at the lower left (e.g. y-intersect of the x-axis = -100). I'd like to move the x-axis so it intersects with y=0. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a method in the ggvis documentation.

Thanks for your help,
Mario

Comment: No really a solution but is this what you want? `
library(ggvis) data_frame(x=rnorm(100,0,50),y=rnorm(100,0,10)) %>%   ggvis(~x,~y) %>%   layer_points() %>%   hide_axis("y") %>% add_axis("y", offset = -241, grid = FALSE)`

Comment: Hey Dambo, thanks for your comment! This definitively goes into the right direction! I'll have to manually try to find the correct offset value, which is very annoying. But so far this is the only solution that might work. I'm very surprised that there is no way to exactly define the "offset" to a specific value of the "other" axis. Cheers, Mario

Comment: Found something under "offset": https://github.com/vega/vega/wiki/Axes  "The offset can also be specified as an object with scale and value properties in which scale refers to the name of a scale and value is a value in the domain of the scale. The resulting value will be a number in the range of the scale." Now sure how the syntax would be: offset = "y" ==0?

Comment: Here is the solution: 
x_off <- scaled_value("y", 0)
add_axis("x", offset= x_off)
This will draw the x-axis to intersect with y=0.

Thanks again for pointing me into the right direction, Dambo.